# Question about the original assignee in this patent

Tags: inventorship, assignee

In reference to the patent: [US3450248](https://www.google.com/patents/US3450248)

Who or what is Roto Rico Co Inc and how can i find them.

Comment: I'm voting to close this question as off-topic because this site is about patents, not the owners. We don't know about random companys nor does patent law/etc. Help with this.

Answer (score 1):

How do you find a company? You search on the internet. A Google search yielded this: https://www.ca-registry.com/C0480237-roto-rico-co-inc amongst other hits. Evidently, the company has dissolved.